# PHP form - Why validation doesn´t work?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

I´m trying to validate a simple PHP form with HTML code but it doesn´t work properly.

Here you are HTML code:

```
 <form action="expresscontactform.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

    <label>Name </label><input id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['Name']; ?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $errors[1]; ?> </span> 
    <label>Email </label><input id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['Email']; ?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $errors[4]; ?> </span> 
    <label>Phone </label><input id="Phone" name="Phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['Phone']; ?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $errors[2]; ?> </span> 
    <label>Country of origin</label><input id="Country" name="Country" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['Country']; ?>">
        <span class="error"> <?php echo $errors[3]; ?> </span> 
    <label>Message </label><textarea id="message" cols="5" rows="5" name="Message"></textarea>

    <input value="Send" class="send_request_new" type="submit">             
</form>
```

And this is PHP code (on the server):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['send_request_new'])){
    $errors = array();

    if($_POST['Name'] == ''){
        $errors[1] = '<span class="error">Please type your name</span>';
    }else if($_POST['Phone'] == ''){
        $errors[2] = '<span class="error">Please type your phone number</span>';
    }else if($_POST['Country'] == ''){
        $errors[3] = '<span class="error">Please type your country</span>';
    }else{

    $EmailFrom = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
    $EmailTo = 'webmaster@theacademy.co,' . $EmailFrom;
    $Subject = "Online Application Form";
    $name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
    $phone = $_POST['Phone'];
    $country = $_POST['Country'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];


    $header = 'From: ' . $EmailFrom . " \r\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
    $header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

    // prepare email body text
    $Body .= "Contact form";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "This is an automatically generated e-mail, to inform you that we received your request. We will contact you as soon as possible.";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Kind regards";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "**********************************************";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "The Academy";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "::::::::::::::::::::::::::";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Your Request:";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "::::::::::::::::::::::::::";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Name: ";
    $Body .= $name;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Phone: ";
    $Body .= $phone;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Country: ";
    $Body .= $country;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Email: ";
    $Body .= $EmailFrom;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Message: ";
    $Body .= $message;
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Sent on " . date('d/m/Y', time());
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "\n";
    $Body .= "Last visited page: ";
    $Body .= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if(mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $header)){
            $result = '<div class="result_ok">Email sent successfully</div>';
            // If successfully we reset all the fields
            $_POST['nombre'] = '';
            $_POST['email'] = '';
            $_POST['asunto'] = '';
            $_POST['mensaje'] = '';

            header("refresh:3;url=http://www.myexample.co/");
        }else{
            $result = '<div class="result_fail">Error!!</div>';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I think there is a mistake in the line below:

```
<span class="error"> <?php echo $errors[1]; ?> </span>
```

But I don´t know where exactly.

One more question, how can I set "The Academy" as email sender?

I don´t know if this is the best way to validate a form, if someone show me other way I will be thankful to learn.

I appreciate a lot if anyone can help me, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: while it is good idea validate with php on the server, things like displaying errors should be done on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your comment meda.

How can I do it? Because I want to validate the form on the server but I want to show errors message on the client side

Comment: For example jquery validation or html required attributes

Comment: Do you recommend me a double validation? First on the client side and after that on the server?

Comment: Yes definitely the advantage is better user experience since you dont process validation on the server. Better performance while keeping it still safe with server validation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your code's execution is dependant on this conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['send_request_new']))` where it's looking for a "named" element called `send_request_new` therefore would never execute.

Your present (unnamed) submit button

```
<input value="Send" class="send_request_new" type="submit">
```

this should be changed to:

```
<input value="Send" class="send_request_new" type="submit" name="send_request_new">
```

you have a class named that way, instead of a `name`.

In order to get it to work, you would need to place your entire HTML/PHP inside the same page and use `action=""`

I noticed you don't have one for your Email and the message, only for the name/phone number and country.

---

Plus, to use a personalized method for the sender's name:

Base yourself on the following:

```
$Name = "The Academy";
$email = "email@example.com";

$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
```

---

You can use some of the filters on PHP.net to validate and protect against XSS injection:

-**http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php**

One of which being `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your supporting Fred -ii-

I have another question...would be possible to send two different emails when someone fills the form. I mean... send an email to the person who fills the form and other to the academy with different information.

For example, the email to the person who fills the form with this elements:

Name
Email
Phone
Country

And the email to the academy with same elements plus another more like:

Name
Email
Phone
Country
`Last visited page: "; $Body .= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`

Comment: You're welcome. You can setup another similar `mail()` function underneath what's presently there, using different variables. @laluk Basically doubling what you have now. Mail can't handle two different sets of variables really, using only one `mail()` function.